# File name for Display Template with IEnumerable<T> objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to create a DisplayTemplate to handle multiples values of a specific class called `Tipificacion`. Now, I know that if name my template with the name of my datatype, when i called the `DisplayFor` Method it's going to look my specific template that I designed for my class. But when it's a `IEnumerable<Tipicacion>` as datatype what name I could put to name of the file the automatic handle this models???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**UIHint Attribute**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint.aspx) in your Model above this specific property, specify the name of the View (*or DisplayTemplate*) that you wish to use to display it, for example:

```
[UIHint("Tipificacion")]
public IEnumerable<Tipicaion> MyTipificacions {get; set;}
```

so if you name your DisplayTemplate "Tipificacions" and set the model type at the top of your view as such:

```
@model IEnumerable<Tipificacion>
```

it should work just fine.